# How dynamic is the Box /search API?

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

I'm using the Box search API to try to locate files on my Box account.

I'm finding that when I move files around, even though those files are on my account on the server, when I search for them, they are not found. They were found in the original location.

Should the /search API reflect the current state of my account? Or is there some sort of caching.

This seems to especially happen with files moved to subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small delay where Box has to reindex your changed files, so updates won't be seen immediately in real-time.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Given that info, do you know of a better way to get the ID for a file given a filename/location on the local file system? My thought was to search by name, but it sounds like that won't be reliable.

Comment: There really isn't a quick way of getting a file by path on Box since everything is designed around IDs. Using search or walking the file tree is really the only way. Ideally, you should only have to find the file once and then store its ID somewhere so you can quickly access it again later.

Comment: Are the IDs by chance stored on the filesystem somehow (on either Mac or Windows)?